# How To Assign Breadcrumb To Commerce Kickstart Omega Collection Or Category?

Tags: commerce, theming, breadcrumbs

[image]How does one assign 'Collection' or other Taxonomy vocabularies to the Crumbs that Kickstart Omega uses. They give examples for Content Types but not for taxonomies.

So any pages based on taxonomies just show 'Home' as the breadcrumb.

I've looked in admin/structure/crumbs and the text pane seems to be correct for some tests I ran with the Debug tab. (ie. the item appears to be in the key menu.link_title.menu-specialties) but I don't know what to -do- with that information.

Maybe there is a -straightforward- tutorial on how to configure this text file?

Below is a screen cap of the crumbs screen I'm seeing.

Comment: Before I post yet another answer, can you post a link to the documentation you were looking at so far? I am not that familiar with Kickstart, but I am curious.

Comment: As for the textarea: You simply move lines up and down with cut+paste.

Comment: Btw what page are you actually creating a breadcrumb for? and how do you expect the breadcrumb to look like? Are we talking about the breadcrumb ON taxonomy term pages? Or are we talking about the breadcrumb for nodes that are tagged with a taxonomy term?

Comment: Can we take this to PM? andreas (at) dqxtech.net, or IRC #drupal and write "donquixote" to get my attention.

Comment: I have to leave for today, but will do. THANKS FOR HELPING!

Answer (score 0):

Version:
First, i usually work with the latest Crumbs version from the 7.x-2.x branch.
If you have problems with the latest version, you should report them in the issue queue. But then you can downgrade either to 7.x-2.0-beta13 or to the 7.x-1.x branch.
Upgrade and downgrade should work fine (I think), but you should clear the caches if you do. Also I don't guarantee if your Crumbs settings are all kept or some of them are lost. Let me know in the comments :)
(Probably this paragraph will soon be obsolete)

Entity parent settings:
I don't remember how much of that is in the 7.x-1.x branch. But in the recent versions, you go to `admin/structure/crumbs/entity-parent/taxonomy-term` and configure the parent path. That's it.

Plugin weights:
The plugin will be available as `crumbs.entityParent.taxonomy_term.categories` on the weights configuration form. But probably you don't need to do anything there, the plugin will already be enabled through the general wildcard "*".

Comment: I don't know how to reply. There is no 'admin/structure/crumbs/entity-parent/taxonomy-term' page. There is only an admin/structure/crumbs page... which consists of a text pane where one enters a number of rules in three broad 'sections'. Maybe I'm missing something stupidly obvious? I updated the question with a screen cap.

Comment: As mentioned, it depends on the version of Crumbs you use, and you need to clear caches. Maybe also run update.php, but I don't think it is absolutely required. Try either 7.x-2.0-beta13 or 7.x-2.0-beta19 (or up).

Comment: Btw this is quite a useful observation, if Kickstart still uses crumbs-7.x-1.*, then it is time I release a stable 7.x-2.0.

Comment: Kickstart2 uses 7.x-1.10. So... Next stupid question: I have had REAL bad luck 'updating' any of the modules included in Kickstart2. I've been told they are of a single piece and that I should simply wait for Commerce Guys to release an update to the whole suite.

So you're saying that your instructions are for 7.x-2? It sounds like this is a big change. If I install it and I run into problems, is there a way to roll it back to 7.x.1? Sorry for sounding so 'noob' but I'm getting increasingly frustrated. The whole Drupal system just seems so 'fragile'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not involved in Kickstart, and I don't know the reasons why you should not update any individual module. I imagine the problem is that if you update Kickstart again, then it will overwrite the update to Crumbs, because it is in the same folder. I think you should make this a new question or post a support request in the Kickstart issue queue, "why can't I update my modules".

Comment: This being said, you now have two options: 1. You manage to update Crumbs to a newer version, disregarding the advice given for Kickstart. I'd say Crumbs is well-behaved enough that you can risk to try this and revert later if you are not happy. 2. You work with the older version, and still manage to get the breadcrumbs you want. I think I might post a new answer here in this stackexchange question, how to do this with crumbs-7.x-1.x.

Comment: I look forward to your new answer. The problem with posting questions on drupal.org Kickstart or Commerce Guys forum is that it seems dead. Or rather, they only seem to post info on their fabulous new D8 update. Which drives me nuts. Thx.